# Unfortunately, lastRide has stopped (Android)

Tags: android

I keep getting this error on emulator:

I copied this from a tutorial and still won't work. When I run my app it says - Unfortunately, lastRide has stopped. Any Ideas?

No errors are given in the console though.

main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <CheckBox android:text="rawted" />

        <CheckBox android:text="rawted" />

        <CheckBox android:text="rawted" />

         <CheckBox android:text="rawted" />
          </LinearLayout>

         </LinearLayout>

       </TabHost>
```

lastRideActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1")
            .setContent(R.id.fr));

}
```

Comment: can you the send tutorial link which you referred ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move `setContentView` so that it occurs before you call for the tabhost.

When you use `getTabHost`the framework is trying to find the widget in the active view, but can't because no view has been set yet.

Comment: Thank you sir. Can also tell me how I would add more content to each Tab?

Comment: In the implementation you are showing you can add to the view heirarchy and simply point `setContent` to the topmost level.  You would replace the `textview1` element in the XML you posted with your new layout and then point the `setContent` to the topmost level of the new layout.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the meaning of content. I mean like I want to add more than one checkbox in each tab. But not vertically, like under each other checkbox.

Comment: Same thing, modify the xml layout you posted by adding checkboxes wrapped in a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout in place of one of the TextViews and point `setContent` to the LinearLayout (or RelativeLayout)

Comment: so make another xml file? or use the same one? would it be like setContentView(R.id.LinearLayout); ?

Comment: Use the same one.  And `setContentView` is to set the main view (the one holding your tabhost).  For the the tab you want to add these checkboxes to you would use `setContent(R.id.yourlayoutid)`

Comment: okay thanks, just one more question, what is the code for adding the setcontent. How do I know which tab I'm setting the layout for?

Comment: Umm, it's in the code you posted in your question...  `mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.id.textview1));`.  Right there at the end is the setContent we've been discussing, and if you change it there you are changing it for TAB 1.

Comment: Update your question with your new xml so we can see what you've got.

Comment: You needed to keep the FrameLayout.  The LinearLayout goes inside the FrameLayout (like the TextViews did).  Revert to what you had and just replace *one* of the TextViews with your new LinearLayout and see if that works.  If you have other issues, you should really start a new question... this comment thread is quite long enough already.  :)

Comment: @Barack okay, I posted the new question. Please help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12395/discussion-between-yusef-bee-and-barak)

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost(); // declare as TabHost in your code
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

**To**

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost(); // declare as TabHost in your code
```

always remember when you try to reference any control (Button,TextView,TabHost) by its ids.
You must always do it after calling setContentView.

Comment: Thank you sir. Can also tell me how I would add more content to each Tab?